# Memory values to ASCII

Tags: memory, assembly, reverse-engineering

Say I am de-compileing code and I come across the values:
cmp, 0x539

Which, because I wrote the code, know it stands for 1337 (0x539).
Say I come across this and I didn't know what the value was... how can I convert 0x539 into ASCII...

Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: What do you mean by converting to ASCII? There's no such ASCII character.

Comment: So, you want to convert an integer into its decimal string representation? What, exactly, is your input and output?

Comment: I meant as in readable human format. Say I come across cmp, 0x763. How would I be able to find out, or convert, 0x763 into string (integer) or whatever...

Comment: What format is it in, originally? A hex-formatted string, an integer, or what?

Comment: Originally it is an integer. The program asks the user for a number.

Comment: For example the value 10 would be 0xa. 
But if I didn't know what value was hardcoded into the program, how would I go about converting the "0xwhatever" back into its integer representation

Comment: An integer is already in an integer representation. Though it's likely that you actually want to convert an integer into a base-10 (decimal) formatted string. Forget ASCII; that has nothing to do with your situation.

Comment: Ahh nevermind. I managed to solve it :) Thanks for the tips though.

Answer (score 1):

they are both ascii and both human readable.  0x539 is base 16 and 1337 is base 10.  with base ten numbers the right most number 7 in this case is in the ones column, you multiply that by 10 to the power 0 (one) then next column is multiplied by 10 to the power 1 the next 10 to teh power 2, the fourth 10 to the power 3 and so on.  So when you read a base 10 number as a human that number is  (1*(10^3))+(3*(10^2))+(3*(10^1))+(7*(10^0)).  Or we also learned it as 1 thousand (10^3), 3 hundred, 3 tens or thirty, 7 ones or 7.   Same is true for any base, for hex 0x539 is (9*(16^0))+(3*(16^1))+(5*(16^2)).  in binary 0x539 is 0b010100111001 which can be read as (1*(2^0))+(0*(2^1))+(0*(2^2))+(1*(2^3))+...  that number 0b010100111001 is octal 2471
which can be read as (1*(8^0))+(7*(8^1))+(4*(8^2))+(2*(8^3))

All the processor cares about is ones and zeros based on some voltage standard used by the logic gates, everything else is in the eyes of the beholder, some bits might be considered an address, or ascii characters, or a phone number, or a floating point number, whatever, the processor doesnt care, its just bits.  The disassembler will sometimes show you both decimal and hex being two popular formats you probably used one or the other to create that number (if it is an immediate that you created/programmed).  Not long ago if at all it would have been decimal and octal instead of decimal and hex or maybe octal only no decimal.

All the forms are human readable though, the 0x symbol or an h at the end or some folk use 16# or $ to all indicate hex, very human readable I know this is a hex number and know how to read base 16 hex.  if not you assume it is decimal, also very human readable.